# Parse user save throws an error without any hint

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to save an user on the Parse User table using

```
user.save(null,{
                                        success: function(savedUser){
                                            alert("We saved parseID");
                                        },
                                        error: function(error){
                                            alert('Error'+JSON.stringify(error));
                                        }
                                    })
```

Unfortunately the error is thrown which contains the object I'm trying to save:

```
 {"username":"ffsdfsd","password":"gdfgfdd","createAt":2016-09-21T13:13:18.965Z", "updatedAt":"2016-09-21T13:13:18.965Z","ACL":{"*":{"read":true},"2FUmrere":{"read":true,"write":true}},"sessionToken":"fdgfdgdgdgdf","objectId":"3ffd3f"}
```

Any idea? Is it something related to the ACL setting (only read permission)?

Answer (score 0):

if the user that you are trying to save is not the logged in user then this is an ACL issue. When a new user is being created in the database the default ACL is **public read** but the write permissions are granted only to the user.

If you still want to save new data on this user without changing the default ACL you need to create a cloud code function and in the cloud code function you need to write the following code:

```js
    user.save(null,{
        sessionToken: request.user.get("sessionToken")
    }).then(function(user){
        // user saved
    },function(error){
        // error handling
    });
```

**please notice** that in my code i sent the logged in user session token (this is required in parse-server) and also i use Promises which is the best practice.